How one uses computer to prove an inequality?
Source: https://keskustelu.suomi24.fi/t/18574666/kinkkinen-epayhtalo-taas
I have heard that there is a proof that $ \frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2 + 15 xz}} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{z^2 + 15 xy}} + \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + 15 zy}}\geq \frac{3}{4}$ as $x>0, y>0, z>0.$ Can one use computer programs or programming to find a rigorous proof of the inequality above?
My effort:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Define the function
def f(x):
    return x[0] / np.sqrt(x[1]**2 + 15 * x[0] * x[2]) + \
    x[1] / np.sqrt(x[2]**2 + 15 * x[0] * x[1]) + \
    x[2] / np.sqrt(x[0]**2 + 15 * x[1] * x[2])

# Initial guess
x0 = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

# Constraints (x > 0, y > 0, z > 0)
bounds = [(1e-5, None), (1e-5, None), (1e-5, None)]

# Minimize
result = minimize(f, x0, method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bounds)

print("Minimum value:", result.fun)
print("Minimum point:", result.x)


Welcome to Scicomp!
Where have you heard that? What have you tried so far?

Seems to me that's a bit of numerical verification, not a mathematical proof.

With a numerical calculation, one can mathematically rigorously prove an inequality for integer numbers (if there is a finite set of those),  but not for real numbers. Probably some manipulation of this inequality with Mathematica can help bring it to some standard inequality form, I suspect it will be the AM-GM inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality

One can use a computer algebra system to analyze the Hessian and find critical points of this function. There are only 3 variables so there are explicit expressions for the Hessian eigenvalues

@whpowell96 This is tricky to do on this inequality, though, because the minimizers are not isolated points (all points of the form (a,a,a)).

Even when working with real numbers, some rigorous results can be obtained using Interval Arithmetic and certified computation.
Your problem is not particularly well-suited for this, since the inequality is sharp, the domain is unbounded, and there are an infinite number of minimizers (all points of the form $(a,a,a)$).
In any case, if one de-homogenizes by setting $x=1$ (which can be obtained without loss of generality with a suitable scaling), and restricts the domain to $y,z\in [1/10,10]$, then the excellent Julia package IntervalOptimisation.jl can be used to give a (fully rigorous!) computational proof that the minimum is between 0.7496840634691095 and 0.7500000002193689 in 2107 seconds on my computer:
julia> using IntervalOptimisation
julia> using IntervalArithmetic
julia> @time global_min, minimisers = minimise(V -> ((y,z) = V; 1/sqrt(y^2+15*1*z) + y/sqrt(z^2+15*1*y) + z/sqrt(1^2+15*z*y)), (0.1..10) × (0.1..10));
2106.154371 seconds (13.78 G allocations: 1.348 TiB, 0.79% gc time, 0.02% compilation time)
julia> global_min.lo
0.7496840634691095
julia> global_min.hi
0.7500000002193689

One can probably get more accurate results (in more time!) by reducing the on the minimizers, which is 1e-3 by default.

It is a good point that numerical computations may include the round-off error bars which would guarantee a certain interval for the true answer. This way, if one knows apriori that there is a global minimum in a certain range of x,y,z, then one can bracket the minimum value with numerical calculations. But how can numerical calculations find that there is a global minimum there? This requires analytic investigation, beyond numerical calculations.

@MaximUmansky This method also proves that there is a global minimum. The main idea of the algorithm (Moore-Skelboe) is that by tracking the error in numerical computations you can determine when an interval does not contain the global minimum for sure, and then work by bisection, determining smaller and smaller candidate intervals for the minimum.

I don't think it's been implemented in IntervalArithmetic, but in principle you can also work with intervals containing $\infty$ and pass the whole $\mathbb{R}_+$. I restricted to [1/10,10] because I was afraid it would not terminate.

According to recent news, AI performed at highest levels solving
International Mathematical Olympiad problems, https://deepmind.google/discover/blog/ai-solves-imo-problems-at-silver-medal-level/. So, probably Google DeepMind AlphaProof could solve this problem analytically; and if not now, then most likely AI will be able to handle it in the near future.
But aside from a possible AI analytic solution, a numerical calculation with a computer can certainly assist proving the inequality. First, one should note that the function
$
f(x,y,z) = 
\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2 + 15 x z}} +
\frac{y}{\sqrt{z^2 + 15 x y}} +
\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + 15 y z}}
$
has the scale invariance property: $f(\alpha x, \alpha y, \alpha z)=f(x,y,z)$ for any $\alpha > 0$. This means that it is enough to prove the inequality on the surface of a unit sphere within the octant $x>0,y>0,z>0$, so the problem is converted from 3D to 2D.
Next, one can write the function $f(x,y,z)$ on the unit sphere in terms of the polar angle $\theta$ and azimuthal angle $\phi$, using $z=\cos(\theta)$, $x=\sin(\theta) \cos(\phi)$, $x=\sin(\theta) \sin(\phi)$. Then, calculating numerically the values of the function, one can plot it and find a strong indication that there is a global minimum, and the value there is indeed close to 3/4.

This is as far as you can go with numerical calculation here; next step would be doing some trigonometric algebra (possibly with Mathematica etc.) to prove that there is indeed a single global minimum in the middle of the $\theta, \phi$ domain; then by the symmetry it must correspond to the point $x$=$y$=$z$=1 where the value is $f$=3/4.

In Mathemaitca code:
Resolve[ForAll[{x, y, z}, x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, 
  x/Sqrt[y^2 + 15 x*z] + y/Sqrt[z^2 + 15 x*y] + z/Sqrt[x^2 + 15 z*y] >=
    3/4], Reals]


Interesting, does Mathematica succeed in proving this inequality? How long does it take?
